# Help me identify this connector

Tags: connector

Can you help me identify this connector please ?
It is used to connect a small 5V fan to a PCB. The pitch is about 1mm. It is written "D3" on the plug. It looks like a JST PH but longer.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please list dimensions and pitch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a [Molex Panelmate](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_1p2&s=Panelmate) (my site). The pitch is 1.25 mm.

- Male PCB header: [Molex 0537800270](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0537800270/699054)
- Female plug housing: [Molex 0511460200](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0511460200/356052)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :D

Comment: Humm do you know where I can find a cable with the 0511460200 female plug housing ?

Comment: That's a new question. I'd tell you start a new thread, but past history tells me that the moderators would remove it for violating the "product recommendations" rule. Therefore, I suggest you ask in some other forum that doesn't mind such questions. /r/AskElectronics is on strike, so that's out. Try the EVBlog or the AllAboutCircuits forums.

Comment: @DavideAndrea wow amazing web site